# Connect Panasonic JT-B1 to PC

Tags: android

I have a Panasonic device and I'm trying to develop a basic android application, but I cannot connect this device with Android Studio or Eclipse. 
Is there a Driver I need to install? (like Samsung Kies for Samsung devices).

Answer (score 1):

The driver may be [downloaded from here](http://panasonic.biz/it/tablet/b1/driver/JT-B1_ADB_usb_driver.zip). It's linked from the [Japanese page here](http://panasonic.biz/it/tablet/b1/catalog.html), but it should be bilingual.

Answer (score 0):

Official drivers can be found here:
http://www.panasonic.com/business/toughbook/computer-support-search-downloads.asp

On windows 8 you might need to disable digitally signed drivers like so before installing the driver:

1. From the Metro or Desktop
2. Bring up Charms by mouseing over to the right of the screen
3. Go to Settings
4. More PC Settings
5. General
6. Advanced Startup > Restart Now
7. Trouble shoot
8. Advanced options
9. Windows startup options
10. Restart
11. Click on 'Disable driver signature enforcement
12. Reboot
13. Install the driver

Thanks to [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/hardware/how-can-i-force-windows-8-to-install-non-digitally/da779859-9d57-4f38-ab2e-22ab8b31c0b8) guy for the help: